# Attempt to create an instance of field that already has an instance of that field

Tags: 7

how can i check if an instance of a field has already been created so that the my_module condition doesn't try to create it again?
something like

```
if(!instance_exist){
//do abc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is [field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle);](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7)

for example:

```
field_info_instance('node', 'field_tags', 'article');
```

will return the field instance if a field 'field_tags' exists on nodes of the content type 'article', NULL otherwise.